# Nuxt3 a simple client side update of data

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have done some past work using Nuxt2 and feel stupid that I cannot figure out how to accomplish a simple update of some local data in **Nuxt 3**. This is on the client side.

Here is the sample

`index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <div>{{ d }}</div>
     <button v-on:click="change">
  </div>
</div>

<script setup>
  let d = 1;

  function change() {
     // increment d
     d++
  }
</script>
```

The value does not change.

I tried browsing to see examples but all focus of Nuxt3 seems to be around async and fetch. I guess that is where the big changes have been made.

Is there any website that has a sample of a typical client app that shows how it is done in Nuxt2 and now in Nuxt 3.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

`index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <div>{{ d }}</div>
     <button v-on:click="change">
  </div>
</div>

<script setup>
  // need to import the functions required
  //import {ref} from 'vue' (not required) as pointed by a user

  // set the initial value
  let d = ref(1);

  function change() {
     // increment d's value
     d.value++
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The import should not be needed normally. Strange.

Comment: You are right @Kissu. I am not sure but I was use the rc candidate a little while back and I kinda remember it threw an error. Now I am using the 3.0.0 ver and it works as you have mentioned. I will update the answer (if it permits). Thanks